# No text when importing DXF to QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to import a drawing from Vectorworks to QGIS, the best I've figured so far is to export as DXF then import into QGIS, it has a couple of issues that I can live with but the major problem is that text is not being imported correctly and I just see a bunch of points.  The same happens for some of the symbols I use but I can live with that.
I've tried adding the plug in AnotherDXFimpprter but that didn't help, is it a problem with the export settings maybe?

The file imports back into vectorworksfine and displays all the text.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to turn labels on then choose the right value for them!

Comment: This isn't actually as good a solution as I thought, a point is created for each item in the VWX data record, so Ideally I need to turn these off as it massively clutters the drawing, but the points are where my labels are coming from so turning points off turns the labels off!  I'm still looking for a good solution if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you save as a DXF then use Project>Import/Export>Import Layers from DWG/DXF
[image: import]

Create an empty geopackage and import the DXF into that - you may get nicely organised annotations depending on the original DWG
[image: geopackage]

In my case the annotations works fine
[image]